# Where are the downloaded data when an issue happens before installing?

Tags: package-management, disk-usage

I installed some Python packages through the terminal, however **after** downloading it, I got an error and had to do it again.

It means I downloaded each package twice and now wonder: where are they ? Can I delete the useless downloaded but not installed packages ?

It's an example of a general problem I have with Ubuntu since I started using it.

Comment: Could you specify how you install the python packages?

Comment: In a terminal I type: `sudo pip3 install package` replacing "package" with the name of the package I want to install.